# Hamachi on Windows 10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hamachi

For a long time now, I have been hosting a small minecraft server for a few of my friends to play on and build. Because I have the **worst** internet provider ever (for privacy reasons I will only say it is Chinese) I can not port forward so I resorted to using a virtual server; aka hamachi. Until the windows 10 update, it has been working fine.

If any of my friends who are connected to my hamachi network try to join my server now they would not be able to connect and the error "connection timed out" would come up.

Something wrong with my hamachi? Or a nation wide problem?

Comment: I guess it's Huawei.

Comment: Actually it is CIK (screw your privacy)

Comment: What's to worry about disclosing your crappy internet provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hamachi is not a simple tool, it emulates a virtual network card which requires the use of custom drivers.

Edit:
The latest release of Hamachi fixes the issue, upgrade and follow their instructions on fixing it http://help.logmein.com/articles/en_US/ReleaseNote/LogMeIn-Hamachi-for-Windows-2-2-0-383/?l=en_US&c=products%3Almihamachi2&fs=RelatedArticle

Paraphrased from the above article:

- Open "Network Connections" via the Control Panel
- Delete the Network Bridge
- Right click and then properties on "Local Area Connection"
- Enable all the items in the list except for "Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Protocol".
- Restart your computer.
- Install the latest version of Hamachi.