# Minecraft and Hamachi: Connection timed out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hamachi

For the longest time, I've been using Hamachi to play with 1 or 2 friends on Minecraft. As of about a year ago, the service has abruptly stopped working (despite me having not changed any settings or preferences, as far as I know) and it just throws a `java.net.ConnectionExeption: Connection timed out: no further information:` error.

I don't know why this is. The Hamachi network is set to be a Home network, I've tried using Radmin VPN as an alternative (which does the exact same thing), I've turned on the "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection", and I've had my friends try to host the server instead. No matter what I do, it returns the same error.

I have looked at other posts on Arqade and all around the Internet regarding people with the same issues, but none of the solutions that are replied seem to actually work with my situation. If anyone here has any idea why Hamachi is doing this, please help me out.

Comment: You should contact that company instead of asking here, they know best why they do what.

Comment: Do any of these answer your question? [Attempting to connect to a Hamachi Minecraft Server gives 'Connection timed out: no further information' error](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/221155/attempting-to-connect-to-a-hamachi-minecraft-server-gives-connection-timed-out) | [Hamachi on Windows 10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/231812/4797) | [How to solve the “io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information” error on Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/316791/4797)